# Clustering base on weights and distance

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, geospatial, k-means

I created this algorithm to make a route for each agent every day so that each agent can 22 close retailers he shall visit today. The code:

```
def clustering(df):
    route_size = 22
    df_with_cluster = pd.DataFrame()
    max_size = route_size
    df['assigned_cluster']=-1
    for agent in tqdm(df['Agents'].unique()):
        temp = df.loc[df['Agents'] == agent].copy()
        X = temp.loc[temp['Agents']== agent][['latitude','longitude']]
        n = math.ceil(len(X)/max_size)
        if len(X)>max_size:
            cls = KMeansConstrained(n_clusters = n,size_max=max_size)
            X['clusters'] = cls.fit_predict(X)
        else:
            X['clusters']=1
        temp = temp.join(X['clusters'])
        temp['assigned_cluster'] = temp.apply(lambda x: x['assigned_cluster'] if pd.isna(x['clusters']) else x['clusters'],axis=1)
        temp = temp.drop(columns=['clusters'])
        df_with_cluster = pd.concat([df_with_cluster,temp])
    df_with_cluster['agent_cluster'] = df_with_cluster['Agents'].map(str) + '_' + df_with_cluster['assigned_cluster'].map(str)
    return df_with_cluster
```

The problem with that code is that it lacks control over who gets clustered, it's random!

It clusters the retailers regardless of the score, it just gives you the closest 22 retailers for each agent.

I have a column in my `df` called '`score`'.

I want to weight the 22 retailers given to each agent to make it have this proportion for example {3 : 0.7, 2 : 0.2, 1 : 0.1}.
I guess if you managed to do this, we will run into another problem which is the distance of the route!
The retailers for example are chosen on the proportions declared above, some retailers who are scored 3 are way too far from retailers who scored 2 and so on, One way to fix this is to think of the highest score as the highest priority to visit. Once clustered the highest score, the code shall take the centroid of that cluster and begin to measure the distance in kilometers between that centroids and other centroids that will be created after it for that agent only, that will make sure that the distance between the centroids cannot be higher than a threshold, for example: 1km. The code should try 5 times to see centroids available for the new score and pick the one with the minimum distance.

I tried sorting the data by the score desc, sampling the data with proportions I declared above without replacement. then making a cluster of the first score, then, take its centroid and then create 10 clusters of other scores and measure the distance between them in km using `haversine` and pick the one with the minimum distance. but I don't know why I keep getting strange results or why the numbers generated are greater than 22 or why the proportions are not correct, there's so much to handle and it got overwhelming for me.

I really hope you can help me guys this has been a head-scratcher for me.
Thanks.